# Explanation of proof of correctness of Gale-Shapley algorithm

Tags: algorithms, proof-explanation

I'm going over a proof that after the Gale-Shapley algo runs, all men and women are matched.

From [these slides](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring13/cos423/lectures/01StableMatching-2x2.pdf)

> Claim. In Gale-Shapley matching, all men and women get matched. Pf.
>   [by contradiction]
>   ・Suppose, for sake of contradiction, that Zeus is
>   not matched upon termination of GS algorithm. 
>   ・Then some woman, say
>   Amy, is not matched upon termination.
>   ・By Observation 2, Amy was never proposed to.
>   ・But, Zeus proposes to everyone, since he ends up
>   unmatched. ▪

and observation 2 is:

> Observation 2. Once a woman is matched, she never becomes unmatched;
>   she only "trades up."

First of all it should be stated that this doesn't work if there aren't equal number of men and number of women.

I don't get the second point; if a man is unmatched how does it imply a women is not matched (unless we do have the assumption |women|=|men|, which we didn't have).

Also, isn't it sort of missing the last step of saying the last 2 points form a contradiction?

I find these types of proofs hard to follow for algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a fundamental assumption for the algorithm that there is an equal number of men and women. Otherwise it would be futile to hope for *any* way of matching everyone, stable or not.

Comment: From the slides the while loop has `WHILE (some man m is unmatched and hasn't proposed to every woman)` what is the point of checking `hasn't proposed to every woman` if the number of men equal the number of women? Am I misinterpreting the statement, as I noticed Wikipedia has `while ∃ free man m who still has a woman w to propose to` which make it sound slightly less to me that the algorithm is checking two separate conditions.

Comment: @Celeritas: It just seems to be a bit of "defensive programming" that will make the algorithm slightly easier to reason about, without actually being executed in a concrete run of the algorithm.